# 96 toyota camry cranks but wont start

Tags: toyota, starting, camry, cranks-wont-run

My boyfriend was trying to get his fans to work. Decided to watch a youtube video and did what the guy said to. I don't know exactly but it consisted of touching wires to the wires on the harness. Well, he said he touched it to what I think is the o2 sensor (right side of engine) and he said it made a spark...after that his car will only crank but won't start.

I have replaced ignition coils and wire for coils and replaced the o2(?) sensor. There's no distributor either.

I was thinking maybe replacing the whole engine harness? As last resort?

I just need to be pointed in the right direction.

Answer (score 2):

Check all the fuses and all the fusable links, hopefully he fried one of them. The colour of the fuse means the amperage that it can handle, it is the bell-shaped curve inside that you are checking. Look for a gap.
[Here's](http://static.oscaroparts.com/content/en/img/email/site_repairtips/img/compare-fuses.jpg) a good vs bad comparison. Fuses are cheap and easy to replace.

Answer (score 2):

If you are playing with engine wirings, always disconnect the battery. ECU will never fail and will last forever unless something mechanically damages it, or you have a shortage where it is not acceptable. Normally ECU works on 12v, sensors 5v. ECU is very sensitive box, and it "burns" if you mess up the wires. I personally saw my co-worker "repairing" a plug on a running ECU. So the engine stopped and £2000 ECU became a scrap.

---

The only recomendation I can give is to diagnose using a OBD2 or ask in a garage for diagnostic... Or if you have an access, borrow a ECU from the same model car somewhere.

---

P.S. What kind of fans was it? What for? Can you post a link of a video please?

Comment: I'd assume it was the radiator or a/c condenser fan since it's in the engine compartment.

Comment: I'm just wondering why would he need to touch any sensor wires.. Was it an intense to repair something or "upgrade".. Because if he tried to take electricity form a sensor, then he have overloaded a ECU, and there is no fuses between ECU and sensors. If you could just find out what fan it is and the video link, surely we could find an issue.